# number as a result in select in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I run query:

```
SELECT ifnull(TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF( a.ending, a.begining ))/60,0)  
FROM visits` a
```

and I wouls like  NUMBER as a result

but i recived like this

```
0.0000
50.0000
50.0000
0.0000
0.0000
50.0000
```

I expect as below:

```
0
50
50
0
0
50
```

or 50,00

it means I need return number

Comment: `50.000` is  a number you mean integer? also `50,00` use `,` as decimal depend on your regional settings.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT CAST( ifnull( TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF( a.ending, a.begining ))/60,
                      0 )
             AS unsigned ) 
 FROM visits` a
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INT) FROM visits a LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: I change int for unsigned, that help?

Answer (score 0):

To get integer result, use `DIV` insted of `/`. Something like this:

```
SELECT IFNULL( TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF( a.ending, a.begining ) ) DIV 60, 0 )
FROM visits a
```

Answer (score 0):

ok but somthing wrong with round

if I divide 50/50 result is 0,99 
why ?

something wrong is with type?